# Creating an angularjs exportable value service type in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to create a value service with typescript which has a simple switch case based on values from the collection below

```
 [{
     book_id: 1,
     year_published: 2000
   },
   {
     book_id: 2,
     year_published: 2003
    },
    {
      book_id: 3,
      year_published: 2007
   }]
```

My value is very simple

```
module app.values {

    export function getAge(year){
        let yearDef = null;
        switch(true){
            case (year > 2003):
            yearDef = 'Older then 2003';
            break;
            case(year < 2003):
            yearDef = "younger then ";
            break;
            default:
            yearDef = "its 2003";
        }
    }

    angular.module("app").value('yearDefService',{
       getAge: getAge
   });

}
```

In my controller i am not sure what to do, what i have tried seems to fail. I am not creating an interface on the `getAge` so i am not sure how to call it in the constructor.

```
 // Omitting controllers interface 
 static $inject = ["dataService","yearDefService"];
    constructor(public dataService    : app.factory.IDataService,
                public yearDefService : any,
                public getYear         :any
    ){

        var vm = this;
        vm.yearThing = dataService.getAllYearThings();
        vm.getAge = yearDefService.getAge;

       ....
```

Then on the view

```
<ul ng-repeat="year in vm.yearThing">
  <li> <b> year def :</b> {{ vm.getAge(year.year_published) }} </li>
</ul>
```

This is just returning empty and a console.log returns an undefined. I am not sure if i am doing this right at all. Any help would be great.

Comment: Where is the console.log that is returning null located? Or is it angular that is returning null?

Comment: In the controller if i set `console.log(yearDefService(2000);` that will return undefined, and in the view there is just nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch statement is probably incorrect:

```
export function getAge(year){
        let yearDef = null;
        switch(true){
            case (year > 2003):
            yearDef = 'Older then 2003';
            break;
            case(year < 2003):
            yearDef = "younger then ";
            break;
            default:
            yearDef = "its 2003";
        }
    }
```

A `switch` can't operate on expressions cases and even then the function `getAge` will never return anything. Which explains the `undefined`. Change it to something like this:

```
export function getAge(year) {
  if(year > 2003) {
    return 'Older then 2003';
  } else if(year < 2003) {
    return 'Younger then ';
  } 

  return 'It\'s 2003!';
}
```